# Replacing ceiling fixture that operates from four switch locations

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

The box has one black, one white, and a ground wire. The new fixture has the same. I connected black-to-black, white-to-white, and the ground to ground.

The problem is the light will not turn on from all switches. It seams to be determined by which switch was used to turn the light off.

What do I need to do to correct the issue?

Comment: The box should have a black, a white (which is the neutral) and a bare copper ground.  Did the old light work from all 4 switches?  What was the reason to replace the light.?

Comment: Did it work before you switched fixtures?

Comment: I edited the question to reflect proper terminology. "white" is usually (and pretty definitely here) "neutral". Ground and neutral are two different things, and based on the references to neutral, I assume this was a bare copper wire, which is ground. If the "neutral" as originally listed was anything but green or bare then please note that as it is very important information.

Comment: Are you *sure* all the switches worked before? Can you carefully take each switch out of the wall and, without disconnecting any wires, take pictures showing all the wires going to each switch?

Comment: If it was working before you just need to put the wiring back the way it was.  https://www.how-to-wire-it.com/wiring-a-4-way-switch.html